# How do I make a modified version of a Racket #lang? (adding / removing a few definitions)

Tags: racket

I'd like to take an existing language, say, `htdp/isl`, and add a few definitions that aren't included by default. I can `(require blah)` at the top of every file, but I want to just be able to write `#lang my-modified-isl` at the top, and get those definitions along with the rest of the language. It's okay if this only works for languages that are "close" to Racket (i.e., have a boring reader).

Comment: I think you can create your own language using `(provide (all-from-out racket) ...)` to  essentially export everything in base Racket already, and what ever you want to add on top, you can do so with `define-synthax` 

docs for [all-from-out](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._all-from-out%29%29)  also check out `all-defined-out` 

Shriram's [Mystery Languages](https://github.com/shriram/mystery-languages) as an example of how to define basic languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket, a `#lang` is basically just any module that provides `#%module-begin` (and optionally a reader/parser). As an example, you can check out my [`SML` package](https://github.com/LeifAndersen/racket-sml/blob/master/main.rkt) (no relation to Standard ML), which is almost vanilla Racket, but a few custom tweaks to make it really good for describing data (like YAML).

Let's say you want to make a version of vanilla Racket, but that includes the function [`standard-fish`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/More_Pict_Constructors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pict%2Fmain..rkt%29._standard-fish%29%29), and lacks a divide (`/`) function. You could make your file:

```
#lang racket ; custom-racket.rkt
(require pict)
(provide (except-out (all-from-out racket) /)
         standard-fish)
```

And now you can use [`s-exp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-languages.html#%28part._s-exp%29) to put your new language in the `#lang` line:

```
#lang s-exp "custom-racket.rkt"
(standard-fish) ; A fish
(/ 10 2) ; Error, `/` undefined
```

(Note that if you want to get rid of S-Expressions entirely and replace the reader, you would use [`#lang reader`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-lang_reader.html) instead.)

Finally, you can package your file into a custom Racket package to use directly. Rename `custom-racket.rkt` from above to `custom-racket/main.rkt`, add an `info.rkt` file, and install the package:

```
$ mkdir custom-racket
$ cd custom-racket
$ vim main.rkt
  #lang racket ; custom-racket.rkt
  (require pict)
  (provide (except-out (all-from-out racket) /)
           standard-fish)
  (module reader syntax/module-reader
    custom-lang)
$ vim info.rkt
  #lang info
  (define collection "custom-racket")
$ raco pkg install
```

And now you can use `custom-racket` directly in the `#lang` line:

```
#lang custom-racket
(standard-fish) ; A fish
(/ 10 2) ; Error, `/` undefined
```